# How to use polymer-redux with polymer-build?

Tags: polymer, redux, polymer-starter-kit

I've currently started a new project based on [Polymer Custom Build](https://github.com/PolymerElements/generator-polymer-init-custom-build). I've modified the project in order to add usage of [polymer-redux](https://github.com/tur-nr/polymer-redux). Since then, when trying to build a bundled project using the command `gulp build`, I have the following problem

> [unknown-polymer-behavior] - Unable to resolve behavior `ReduxBehavior`. Did you import it? Is it annotated with @polymerBehavior?

Declaring the ReduxBehavior is done using `ReduxBehavior = PolymerRedux(store);` which is not very usual.

Anybody succeeded to make both of polymer-build and polymer-redux work together ?

Comment: Have you resolved this issue yet?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the sample repo for Polymer 2 with Redux Application.

https://github.com/kumarargutech/polymer-redux

I hope it's helpful to you!

Answer (score 0):

You can check out this [Polycast edition](https://youtu.be/PahsgJn0sgU?list=PLNYkxOF6rcIDdS7HWIC_BYRunV6MHs5xo).

Here is the [code](https://github.com/Polymer/polycasts/tree/master/ep61-redux)

You can also check the [Simpla](https://github.com/simplaio/simpla) repo

Basically you create a `polymer-redux-store-html`:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer-redux/polymer-redux.html">
        <script>
            var ReduxBehavior = new PolymerRedux(THG.store);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

and include it in any element where you need the `ReduxBehavior`

Comment: Thanks Umit. This is precisely what I did. The website works well if I don't try to create a bundled version using `gulp build`. My question is about the creation of the bundled version, which doesn't seem to support the usage of redux.

Comment: that's weird, maybe there is an issue with ordering of the bundled imports. Can you check in the bundled output if the `polymer-redux-store` is included ?