# Potential conflict between polymer build and tur-nr/polymer-redux

Tags: redux, polymer

#### Description

I am experiencing unexpected errors when running `polymer build` after installing and using `tur-nr/polymer-redux`. [Here is the demo repo](https://github.com/maria-le/redux).

#### Versions & Environment

- polymer-build: v0.18.3  `polymer --version`
- node: v6.10.2
- Operating System: macOS Sierra v10.12.4

#### Steps to reproduce

terminal

```
git clone https://github.com/maria-le/redux # clone remote repo to your local
cd redux                                    # cd into your local repo
bower install                               # install bower dependencies
npm install redux                           # install redux
polymer build                               # attempt build
```

#### Expected results

I expect the build to complete, without errors. Then allow me to serve the packaged build.

#### Actual results

I get the following errors in the terminal.

Error messages

> src/all-locally.html(14,16) error [unknown-polymer-behavior] - Unable to resolve behavior `store`. Did you import it? Is it annotated with @polymerBehavior?
>
> ReduxStore
>
> src/imported-behavior.html(7,16) error [unknown-polymer-behavior] - Unable to resolve behavior `ReduxStore`. Did you import it? Is it annotated with @polymerBehavior?
>
> polymerStore
>
> src/imported-store-as-variable.html(10,16) error [unknown-polymer-behavior] - Unable to resolve behavior `polymerStore`. Did you import it? Is it annotated with @polymerBehavior?
>
> PolymerRedux(reduxStore)
>
> src/imported-store.html(7,16) warning [could-not-determine-behavior-name] - Could not determine behavior name from expression of type
>
> CallExpression
>
> error:   Promise rejection: Error: 3 error(s) occurred during build.
>
> error:   Error: 3 error(s) occurred during build.
>
> at BuildAnalyzer._done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/polymer-build/lib/analyzer.js:229:36)
>
> at BuildAnalyzer. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/polymer-build/lib/analyzer.js:189:26)
>
> at next (native)
>
> at fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/polymer-build/lib/analyzer.js:17:58)
>
> at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)

#### References

- [How to use polymer-redux with polymer-build?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42044277/1640892)
- [polymer lint and polymer-build fail due to ReduxBehavior not registering properly](https://github.com/tur-nr/polymer-redux/issues/62)
- [`@polymerBehavior` should still produce a behavior even if we can't evaluate the expression](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-analyzer/issues/632)

Comment: In error message you get solution. Start from `0.18` version `polymer-cli` throws an error if you use some behavior and doesn't add import of it to your element. Try to add imports for missing behaviors in your elements and try to run `polymer build` again.

Comment: Mowzer : Sample repo for Polymer 2 using Redux. I hope it's helpful to you. 
 https://github.com/kumarargutech/polymer-redux